# Make results in: "LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references"

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

/refbase.bib file:

```
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}

@book{lamport1994latex,
  title={LATEX: a document preparation system: user's guide and reference       manual},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Addison-wesley}
}

@article{lamport1994latex,
  title={LATEX user’s guide and reference manual},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts}
}

@book{7.1.3-1,
address={Niter\'oi},
author={Gomes, L. G. F. F},
publisher={EdUFF},
title={Novela e sociedade no Brasil},
year={1998}}
```

/02-elementos-textuais/1-introducao/contextualizacao_e_motivacao.tex file:

```
\section{Contextualização e Motivação}
\cite{7.1.3-1}
```

/03-elementos-pos-textuais/bibliografia.tex file:

```
 \bibliography{refbase}
```

/main.tex contains:

```
 \usepackage[alf, abnt-emphasize=bf, recuo=0cm, abnt-etal-cite=2, abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite}    % Citações padrão ABNT
```

In {document}:

```
 \include{./03-elementos-pos-textuais/referencias}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you ran BibTeX after running LaTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs.

Comment: @Mico my makefile is runing LaTeX, BibTex, building the index and then three LaTeX runs

Comment: @LucasCardosoSilva - I have no idea what the expression "my makefile" is supposed to mean here. Please elaborate. E.g., which instructions does the makefile contain? Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @LucasCardosoSilva is `bibtex` mentioned in your makefile?

Comment: @Mico sorry, it's a script, but I'm running LaTeX, BibTex, building the index and then three LaTeX runs

Comment: @samcarter yes, it is

Comment: What is the output if you type `bibtex main` in the terminal?

Comment: @LucasCardosoSilva Looks good. If you now do `pdflatex main`, do you still get undefined references?

Comment: @samcarter Ends with: The style file: abntex2-alf.bst
Database file #1: abntex2-options.bib
Database file #2: refbase.bib

Comment: @samcarter I get undefined references

Comment: @LucasCardosoSilva Please try Mico's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Please check if your makefile produces the correct output when running it on the following MWE (minimum working example). If it does *not* produce the correct output, your makefile needs fixing. If it does produce the correct output, then there's something wrong somewhere in your complex system of latex- and bibtex-related files and folders.

[image]

[image]

```
%% save as "test.tex"
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refbase.bib}
@book{7.1.3-1,
  address={Niter\'oi},
  author={Gomes, L. G. F. F},
  publisher={EdUFF},
  title={Novela e sociedade no Brasil},
  year={1998}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{abntex2} % just a guess...
\usepackage[alf, abnt-emphasize=bf, recuo=0cm, 
   abnt-etal-cite=2, abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document} 
\cite{7.1.3-1}
\bibliography{refbase}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The \cite in the example produces a (??) where is suposed to be (GOMES, 1998)

Comment: After I run 2 more times my makefile it works, I will fix it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your comments make it sound like your makefile runs LaTeX (and BibTeX) only once. If that's the case, you may want to look into modifying the makefile so that it always run latex-bibtex-latex-latex, i.e., that latex is run three times in all.